# Display text to a label from another class - JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a GUI screen, and it has a label in it. I now want to set the label with a text as i have shown in below (`Test`). But it's not getting updated. I think there's an error in the follwoing code, where i am recreating a new object of FrameTest in the try block;

```
FrameTest frame = new FrameTest();
frame.setVisible(true); //(the full code given below)
```

The Full Code: Note: the following class is extended from **JFrame**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel lblLabel;

    public  void mainScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FrameTest frame = new FrameTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void writeLabel(String k){
        this.lblLabel.setText(k);

    }


    public FrameTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        lblLabel = new JLabel("LABEL");
        contentPane.add(lblLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Test Class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         FrameTest f = new FrameTest();
         f.mainScreen();
         f.writeLabel("FFFFF");
}}
```

Help, how can i get Text `"FFFFF"` displayed to the label ?

Comment: `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);`  How many times do we have to say it?  Don't set the bounds - `pack()` the frame then  `setLocationByPlatform(true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `mainScreen()` you create a new `FrameTest` that is distinct from the one you create in the `main` routine, so it's actually changing the text, of the invisible frame. Try this instead:

```
private FrameTest frame = this;

public  void mainScreen() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Or simply:

```
public  void mainScreen() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this also works. Can you comment on my answer above ? Is it correct or will i have other issues if i use it later on?

Comment: @MouseEvent why is it necessary to refer the `this` object once again in the function. why don't he just say `this.setVisible(true)` or simply `setVisible(true)` ?

Comment: @sunil `this.setVisible(true)` won't work 'cause it will refer to the `Runnable`, not to the frame, but `setVisible(true)` should work.

Comment: yup.. you are rt. `this` inside the anonymous class will refer to the `Runnable` instance. Error from my side. But we can refer the original `this` as `FrameTest.this`. So we can call like `FrameTest.this.setVisible(true)` instead of re-referring the object

Comment: The style I used is because I wanted to mimic the OP's style.

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to your FrameTest

```
public String readLabel(){
       return this.lblLabel.getText();
}
```

Comment: What i want is to edit the text of the label from the Class `Test`

Answer (score 1):

Change the mainScreen() function to

```
public  void mainScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

remaining code is same

Comment: This is because, in `mainScreen` function, you are creating another instance of JFrame and showing that to the user. In `Test` class you are creating another `JFrame` instance `f`. These two objects are entirely different and changes made to one object cannot be visible in another object.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use your code does not trigger a repaint of your frame or label.
In Swing you can change many Gui Objects, but they are only redrawn in a single batch when requested.
The most usual case when a repaint occurs automatically, is after you return from an event handler. (E.g. a button click or key press)

Comment: No need to do this, `JLabel` triggers it automatically.

Comment: `JLabel` (like many components) calls `revalidate` and `repaint` when you change any number of it's properties.  I agree, sometimes it needs a nudge, but more often then not, Swing will update itself

Answer (score 0):

Replace the try block with;

```
            try {
                setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Everything works!

Comment: But, `FrameTest ` extends from `JFrame`, so i thought i could use `setVisible` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh.. Thank you. So if i remove the `try-catch` will it be Ok ?

Comment: Well, you're right, it does work. (but the reason your first code didn't, that's what I cleared, consider accepting something...)

Comment: The exception handler isn't required as nothing is throwing an exception; MouseEvent's suggestion is correct