# how to modify a JFrame by another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, textarea

I have two JFrames A, and B. B has a textArea. I want to add some text to that TextArea in B by 
clicking a button in A. here is my code:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Text");
btnButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        b.textArea.setText("Button clicked");
    }
});
btnButton_1.setBounds(10, 45, 89, 23);
frmA.getContentPane().add(btnButton_1);
```

- b is object of class B
- textArea is JTextArea variable name in class B

Comment: Try calling `repaint()` in `b` after adding text to the JTextArea

Comment: don't repaint anythign, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE short, runnable, compilable

Comment: you can use b.textArea.append("your text");

Comment: is your textArea public?

Comment: can you explain your answer

Comment: @user3417593 to whom the question is for?

Comment: b.textArea.append("your text"); same thing doesn't work

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13470748/3417593 this works.

Answer (score 0):

Use repaint() method of components.

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Text");
        btnButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b.textArea.setText("Button clicked");
                b.frameB.repaint();
            }
        });
        btnButton_1.setBounds(10, 45, 89, 23);
        frmA.getContentPane().add(btnButton_1);
```

Comment: what is repaint() method. doesn't show up when i press (.) ?

Comment: @user3417593 - please see my updated post. you should repaint the frame itself.

Comment: i repaint the frame, but same thing doesn't work. I also tried to repaint the textArea. again doesn't work. have you tried this ?

Comment: @user3417593 - can you post both java codes? but not whole just the gist.